# Key/values for usePageViewController's options

Tags: ios, ios11, pdfkit

What key/values can I specify in `withViewOptions` parameter of `usePageViewController` method of PDFView of iOS11, PDFKit?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation found in `PDFKit`, `usePageViewController:withViewOptions:` passes the given options to the `UIPageViewController` located in the viewer.

> The `viewOptions` argument is given to the `UIPageViewController` initializer, as a way to pass in page spacing, etc.

`UIPageViewController`'s available options are [`UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrolleroptionspinelocationkey) and [`UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrolleroptioninterpagespacingkey).

Comment: I'd like to get pageCurl transition style, and tried the several ways like
pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: ["style":UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.pageCurl]), or         pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: ["transitionStyle":UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle."pageCurl"]), or         pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: ["transitionStyle":"pageCurl]), but I failed. How should I specify?

Comment: @YasuoAsakawa Do you find a solution?
I also want the pageCurl transition style

Comment: hello, I am running into this problem,  I also want the pageCurl transition style, how can I specify please that?.