# How to create a single page vertical scrolling PDFView in Swift

Tags: swift, pdfview

I am trying to make a vertical scrolling PDFView using the following code:

```
pdfView = PDFView(frame: view.frame)
pdfView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

var documentName: String = "test"

if let documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: documentName, withExtension: "pdf") {
    if let document = PDFDocument(url: documentURL) {
        pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: nil)
        pdfView.document = document
    }
}

self.view.addSubview(pdfView)
```

It displays fine, but the displayDirection is horizontal, not vertical. I'm trying to find a way to set the withViewOptions, but [I can't find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46543946/key-values-for-usepageviewcontrollers-options) relevant info on this.

I checked on SO, and many people suggest to add `displayDirection` but that doesn't see to change anything.

On the other hand, when I try to run the following code:

```
pdfView = PDFView(frame: view.frame)
pdfView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

var documentName: String = "test"

if let documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: documentName, withExtension: "pdf") {
    if let document = PDFDocument(url: documentURL) {
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        pdfView.document = document
    }
}

self.view.addSubview(pdfView)
```

It just displays the first page and it doesn't scroll. I need to add swipe gestures recognizers and the scroll is not smooth. Beside, it seems overkill for a single page scrolling functionality...

Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Try `pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous`

Comment: It’s not the same experience as singlePage... I know it works, but I am looking for a singlePage navigation

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need to do is use the following method from `PDFView`:

`pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: [:])`

[PDFView-PageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview/2877501-usepageviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, DisplayMode = .SinglePage, but this also causes problems with multiple pages, so the displayMode should be taken by the number of pages and changed accordingly.

```
if pdfView.document!.pageCount == 1 {
     pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
}
```